# Unstring Python?

Tags: python

I am a noob,
How do I remove quotations and commas from my list?  Or how do I "unstring"?

Without showing the dictionary (dic), the code I am using looks like this:

```
>>>import itertools
>>>list(itertools.product(dic[2], dic[3])
```

my results looks like this:

```
[('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F')]
```

I would like them to look like this:

```
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF,
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to produce a string, so you can use string manipulation (in particular, the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['A', 'B']
>>> b = ['D', 'E', 'F']
>>> print ', '.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(a, b))
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF
```

Actually you don't even need `itertools`, you could just use a nested comprehension:

```
>>> print ', '.join(x + y for x in a for y in b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [join string method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> p = list( itertools.product( ['a','b','c' ],['e','f','g'] ) )
>>> p
[('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('a', 'g'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('b', 'g'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('c', 'g')]
>>> ', '.join( a+b for (a,b) in p )
'ae, af, ag, be, bf, bg, ce, cf, cg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import sys
yourlist = list(itertools.product(dic[2], dic[3])
sys.stdout.write (yourlist[0][0] + yourlist[0][1])
for i in xrange (1, len(yourlist)):
    sys.stdout.write (", " + yourlist[i][0] + yourlist[i][1])
```

Although other answers use the [join()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method (the correct and 'python' way to do it) I have given you a simple rough and tough solution so I don't kill your current lesson with you trying to figure out how the join() method works.

Comment: That doesn't produce the desired output, though. Maybe you wanted to add a comma at the end of the `print` statements?

Comment: Why write directly to `stdout` rather than using `print()`? Also, I don't feel `join()` is such a hard concept to get, so while I get what you were trying to do, I don't think it benefits anyone.

Comment: @Lattyware: It's actually not very intuitive to make `print` not print trailing whitespace after what you gave it as arguments.

Comment: @NiklasB. In 2.x, this is true. Although a better solution might be to do `from __future__ import print_function` and then use `print(..., end="")` if you are stuck with 2.6/2.7.

Comment: @Lattyware: Sure, I just said it's not very intuitive (and it isn't a lot more readable than `stdout.write`)

Comment: I would argue it's clearer than using `sys.stdout.write()` - especially to non-unix users who may not be familiar with what `stdout` even is.

Comment: Both good points, I definitely think print(..., end="") is the better way to go, but at this point I'll leave it up to the OP

Answer (score 0):

What about this using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
p = [('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F')]

', '.join([''.join(i) for i in p])
```

and [join()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) to concatenate strings gives:

```
AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF
```

Alternatively, a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) would also work (thanks to @Nicklas B reminding me, for some reason list comprehension comes to my mind first):

```
', '.join(''.join(i) for i in p)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
In [61]: l=[('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), 
            ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'F')]

In [62]: ', '.join(t[0]+t[1] for t in l)
Out[62]: 'AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, BF, CD, CE, CF'
```